# How to get $2^p=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ from the equation below?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

The equation is $4^p-2^p-1=0$

How to get $2^p = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$  from that equation?

Please help.

Comment: Let $x=2^p$.  Then your equation is $x^2-x-1=0$.

Comment: @lulu thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Note also that only the positive root has to be considered.

Comment: @egreg yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is $(2^p)^2-2^p-1=0$ with $t=2^p$ we get $$t^2-t-1=0$$ Can you solve this?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your kind help!

Comment: Nice that i could help you, Lara!